# Alert 'bad record mac' after several minutes of proper communication between Java app and C app with OpenSSL

Tags: encryption, ssl, openssl, java, c

Our Java app receives a packet with probably bad_record_mac after a couple of minutes of proper communication with C-based OpenSSL side, then Java socket closes the connection. Full Java stack trace is as follows:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: bad record MAC
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
...some internal code...
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: bad record MAC
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
...some internal code...
```

We've tried Java 6.0_21, 6.0_25, Java 7.0_79, OpenSSL 1.0.1h, 1.0.1u, 1.0.2j, 1.1.0b and 1.1.1 from the development branch. Also tried to use different ciphers - results are the same.

Application message size is about 20...200 bytes. Packet data is correct, the problem is only with message authentication code.

We want to identify which side (Java or OpenSSL) is responsible for error. Could someone help us to debug the communication trace? CAP file with certificate can be downloaded here: https://yadi.sk/d/3cnBUIN3yCRKw

Answer (score 0):

Packet capture is useless to debug this kind of issue, because the communication is encrypted and you'd need to provide the negociated keys. Your best bet is to crank up the debug message on both sides to track down the issue.

Java side, the javax.net.debug property (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) is your best bet to understand the issue.

Comment: There is no useful info in Java log either ([Java logs](https://yadi.sk/d/YXU4mQ77yknKu)). At 17:14:53 SSL session is invalidated because of bad record MAC. OpenSSL log obviously tells that disconnection happened - this is what really Java app do in case of BRM is met. The problem is to identify whether it is OpenSSL sends bad MAC or Java app decodes it incorrectly.

Comment: You can have much more verbose logs with setting javax.net.debug to all

Comment: Unfortunately setting log level to _all_ overheads the system and observer effect comes into play) The system starts to communicate really slow and unstable so a bad MAC was not captured during the past weekend.

Comment: There  is a middle ground before not enough and too much, adjusting the debug level is likely the way here... Crippling performance issues with max debug is surprising to me, maybe there is much more wrong with the machine itself...